# Regex for quote tags php

Tags: php, regex

I need to parse single quoted text (note multiple nested = single) with php, similar to forums quote tag. Example:

```
some nonquoted text1
[quote="person1"]some quoted text11[/quote]
some nonquoted text2
[quote="person2"]some quoted text22[/quote]
etc... with no newlines necessarily...
```

Result should be array like

```
 Array
        (
            ['nonquoted'] => Array
                (
                    [0] => some unquoted text1
                    [1] => some unquoted text2
                )
            ['quoted'] => Array
                {
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => person1
                            [1] => some quoted text11
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => person2
                            [1] => some quoted text22
                        ) 
                 }
        }
```

Comment: ...and what have you tried?

Comment: Here's an example to get you started, it'll only match the quoted content though, and it certainly won't create that pretty structure you're after: http://regex101.com/r/mN0yL1

Comment: Indexed arrays should be used for uniform data, heterogeneous data should be associative arrays. So the inner arrays in `$array['quoted']` should be like `Array ('name' => 'person1', 'text' => 'some quoted text11')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$input= <<<EOL
some nonquoted text1
[quote="person1"]some quoted text11[/quote]
some nonquoted text2
[quote="person2"]some quoted text22[/quote]
EOL;

$result = Array('unquoted'=>Array(), 'quoted'=>Array());

//find [quote] blocks, replace them with nothing, and store the text in $result['quoted']
$unquoted = preg_replace_callback('@\[quote="([^\"]+)"\](.*)\[/quote\]@',function($m) use(&$result){
    $result['quoted'][]=Array($m[1],$m[2]);
},$input);

//what's left is only unquoted lines, so split them into an array
$result['unquoted']=preg_split('@[\r\n]+@',$unquoted);

//your result
print_r($result);
```