# Quote tags regex php - general case

Tags: php, regex

I've asked question about regex for alternate quoted, unquoted, quoted, unquoted... case in this thread: [Regex for quote tags php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20691291/regex-for-quote-tags-php)

I realized I need more general case with preserved items order. Like quoted, unquoted, quoted, quoted, quoted... etc... Also there are **not nested** quotes. I guess it should be done iterative or recursive... I'll explain on example.

```
some unquoted text11
[quote="person1"]some quoted text11[/quote]
[quote="person2"]some quoted text22[/quote]
[quote="person3"]some quoted text33[/quote]
some unquoted text22
...
[quote="person4"]some quoted text44[/quote]
...
```

Resulting array should be:

```
Array   //PRESERVED ORDER
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    ['type'] => unquoted
                    ['name'] => ''
                    ['text'] => some unquoted text11
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    ['type'] => quoted
                    ['name'] => person1
                    ['text'] => some quoted text11
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    ['type'] => quoted
                    ['name'] => person2
                    ['text'] => some quoted text22
                )
            [3] => Array
                (
                    ['type'] => quoted
                    ['name'] => person3
                    ['text'] => some quoted text33
                )
            [4] => Array
                (
                    ['type'] => unquoted
                    ['name'] => ''
                    ['text'] => some unquoted text22
                )

                ...

            [5] => Array
                (
                    ['type'] => quoted
                    ['name'] => person4
                    ['text'] => some quoted text44
                )

                ...
        }
```

Comment: Hey, what about you show us what you have tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions are a bad choice for solving this problem, because they don't offer you the ability to maintain state. The very state you are referring to when you mention nesting. Even for a simple approach that does not allow nested tags, the solution continues to depend on knowing the state of the expression because you want a root element to be identified as such (*per the first element in your expected array*).

Instead, a better solution is to use an already proven and fast single-pass parser like [BBcode](http://php.net/bbcode), which can do a much more effective job and provide far more maintainable code.

Comment: PCRE is a lot more powerful than you think, see the [power of regex](http://nikic.github.io/2012/06/15/The-true-power-of-regular-expressions.html). I've already got a regex solution for this question, but we shouldn't feed the [helpvampire](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/).